# Multiple polyline over each other - bring one "to the front"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

**Is there a way to bring a block's polygon (and its polylines) to the top layer?**

I'm drawing polylines (to form polygons) for blocks in a city. Each block polygon is outlined with white polylines:

```
 block = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: blockCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#ffffff',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        fillOpacity: shadeValue
      }); }
```

When I hover over a block, I want the outline to turn black. I currently have this code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseout', function (event) {
                this.setOptions({
                    strokeColor: '#ffffff'
                });
            });
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseover', function (event) {
                this.setOptions({
                    strokeColor: '#000000'
                });
            });
```

However, it's not working on all the blocks.I think that is because (depending on the order of how the blocks are drawn), sometimes the polylines of other blocks are "above" the current block polylines.

[image]

If I set the white polylines to opacity of 0 (and black to an opacity of 1). **It works fine but I, of course, don't get the pretty white lines between the blocks.**

[image]

Comment: Did you try the [zindex PolylineOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions)? `zIndex | number | The zIndex compared to other polys.`

Comment: No I haven't used that at all. Can you dynamically change that?

Comment: You should be able to. The only issue I have seen with zIndex is that you may need to specifically set it for all your polylines, then the one with the highest value will be on top.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with several overlapping `Polylines`. The way I solved this is by initializing the `Polyline` with a `zIndex`. For you it should look something like:

```
 block = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: blockCoordinates,
    strokeColor: '#ffffff',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#ff0000',
    fillOpacity: shadeValue,
    zIndex: 1
  }); }
```

Now you should able to change the `zIndex` of the `Polylines` using your `mouseover` and `mouseout` events like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseout', function (event) {
    this.setOptions({
        strokeColor: '#ffffff',
        zIndex: 1
    });
});
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseover', function (event) {
    this.setOptions({
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        zIndex: 2
    });
});
```

The initialization isn't strictly necessary, but you could run into unexpected behavior if you don't.